# ENOENT: no such file or directory writing file with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am not sure where I went wrong to get this error:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../dist/index.html'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '../dist/index.html' }
```

I put a `console.log("Build HTML error")` in my code to see if the error fires and it does. I also used `console.log($.html());` to see if the correct HTML is generated and it is.

my code:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../app/index.html', 'utf8', (err, markup) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("grab HTML error");
        return console.log(err);
    }

    const $ = cheerio.load(markup);

    console.log($.html());
    $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">');

    fs.writeFile('../dist/index.html', $.html(), 'utf8', err => {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Build HTML error");
           return console.log(err);
       }
       console.log('index.html written to /dist'.green);
    });
});
```

As you can see, I have the `dist` directory in the correct place and the other files generated from `webpack` are generated and built

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Try using path.resolve() after require'ing "path"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it has to do with your relative path.  You should use the same path strategy you used for `readFile`:

```
fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/../dist/index.html', $.html(), 'utf8', err => {
```